# Output PowerShell variables to a text file

Tags: powershell

I'm new to PowerShell and have a script which loops through Active Directory searching for certain computers. I get several variables and then run functions to check things like [WMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) and registry settings.

In the console, my script runs great and simple [Write-Host](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Write-Host) command prints the data on the screen as I want. I know about [Export-Csv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Export-Csv) when using the pipeline...but I'm not looking to print from the pipeline.

I want to write the variables to a text file, continue the loop, and check the next computer in AD...output the next iteration of the same variables on the next line. Here is my Write-Host:

```
Write-Host ($computer)","($Speed)","($Regcheck)","($OU)
```

Output file:

```
$computer,$Speed,$Regcheck | out-file -filepath C:\temp\scripts\pshell\dump.txt -append -width 200
```

It gives me the data, but each variable is on its own line. Why? I'd like all the variables on one line with comma separation. Is there a simple way to do this akin to VB writeline? My PowerShell version appears to be 2.0.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I usually construct custom objects in these loops, and then add these objects to an array that I can easily manipulate, sort, export to CSV, etc.:

```
# Construct an out-array to use for data export
$OutArray = @()

# The computer loop you already have
foreach ($server in $serverlist)
    {
        # Construct an object
        $myobj = "" | Select "computer", "Speed", "Regcheck"

        # Fill the object
        $myobj.computer = $computer
        $myobj.speed = $speed
        $myobj.regcheck = $regcheck

        # Add the object to the out-array
        $outarray += $myobj

        # Wipe the object just to be sure
        $myobj = $null
    }

# After the loop, export the array to CSV
$outarray | export-csv "somefile.csv"
```

Comment: When I run this, $computer isn't showing with a machine name?  It is showing in the CSV as "System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection"

Comment: Okay, I have no idea where your $computer variable is generated, but the class you're referring to has a ToString method, so you might be able to do this:
$myobj.computer = $computer.ToString().

If that doesnt work I will need to know what exactly you put in your $computer variable.

Comment: This worked!  Thanks.  FYI...the computer variable is pulled direct from AD http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730959.aspx

Comment: Great! I guess out-file does an implicit string conversion whereas export-csv does not. Anyhow, this technique will allow you to slice and dice data and is much more "object-oriented" so AFAIK it's the "right" way to do things (at least in my head:-) )

Answer (score 39):

Use this:

```
"$computer, $Speed, $Regcheck" | out-file -filepath C:\temp\scripts\pshell\dump.txt -append -width 200
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's clean and simple. I bet most people miss the fact that the double quote wrapping the variables is what does the trick.

Answer (score 9):

You can concatenate an array of values together using PowerShell's `-join' operator. Here is an example:

```
$FilePath = '{0}\temp\scripts\pshell\dump.txt' -f $env:SystemDrive;

$Computer = 'pc1';
$Speed = 9001;
$RegCheck = $true;

$Computer,$Speed,$RegCheck -join ',' | Out-File -FilePath $FilePath -Append -Width 200;
```

Output

```
pc1,9001,True
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to use double quotes around the join string.  ","

Answer (score 2):

`$computer,$Speed,$Regcheck` will create an array, and run `out-file` ones per variable = they get seperate lines. If you construct a single string using the variables first, it will show up a single line. Like this:

```
"$computer,$Speed,$Regcheck" | out-file -filepath C:\temp\scripts\pshell\dump.txt -append -width 200
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to avoid creating an array before piping to [Out-File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Out-File).  Rule #1 of PowerShell is that the comma is a special delimiter, and the default behavior is to create an array. Concatenation is done like this.

```
$computer + "," + $Speed + "," + $Regcheck | out-file -filepath C:\temp\scripts\pshell\dump.txt -append -width 200
```

This creates an array of three items.

```
$computer,$Speed,$Regcheck
FYKJ
100
YES
```

vs. concatenation of three items separated by commas.

```
$computer + "," + $Speed + "," + $Regcheck
FYKJ,100,YES
```

Answer (score 1):

I was lead here in my Google searching.  In a show of good faith I have included what I pieced together from parts of this code and other code I've gathered along the way.

```html
# This script is useful if you have attributes or properties that span across several commandlets
# and you wish to export a certain data set but all of the properties you wish to export are not
# included in only one commandlet so you must use more than one to export the data set you want
#
# Created: Joshua Biddle 08/24/2017
# Edited: Joshua Biddle 08/24/2017
#

$A = Get-ADGroupMember "YourGroupName"

# Construct an out-array to use for data export
$Results = @()

foreach ($B in $A)
    {
  # Construct an object
        $myobj = Get-ADuser $B.samAccountName -Properties ScriptPath,Office
  
  # Fill the object
  $Properties = @{
  samAccountName = $myobj.samAccountName
  Name = $myobj.Name 
  Office = $myobj.Office 
  ScriptPath = $myobj.ScriptPath
  }

        # Add the object to the out-array
        $Results += New-Object psobject -Property $Properties
        
  # Wipe the object just to be sure
        $myobj = $null
    }

# After the loop, export the array to CSV
$Results | Select "samAccountName", "Name", "Office", "ScriptPath" | Export-CSV "C:\Temp\YourData.csv"
```

Cheers

Comment: The problem is this output is as a CSV and the request was as a flat file, not a CSV.