# processing sql updates in chunks in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have the following set of example code :

```
foreach($status in $SomeStatus)
        {
            Invoke-Expression("Invoke-SqlCmd -S . -query " + @"
            " Update [DocStatus]
              SET LastModifiedAt = 'something'
              WHERE 
                  DocId='$($status.DocId)'"
"@)
        }
```

however if I have like a 100000 records to update this is too slow .

I want to do something like (for example) :

```
 Do updates in chunks of 1000

    foreach(chunk)
    {
    open file 

    foreach(record in chunk) {
    write to file
    }
    sql-exec(file)
    close file
    }
```

Can anyone show me how I can achieve this in powershell ?

Answer (score 0):

You're essentially doing a cursor via powershell, which doesn't utilize SQL efficiencies.  I recommend you write the values intended to update to file (powershell does this very quickly), perform an import from flat file to the database (100k records is not too big) to a staging table and then do an update statement that handles all the records in one shot.  This way you're not invoking SQL 100k times, it's just twice.

**EDIT**
Here is an example that collects data using a loop and saves it to a CSV file:

[Output PowerShell variables to a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858133/output-powershell-variables-to-a-text-file)

This website (one of many) details how to use powershell to create a staging table and to import data into it:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Import-Large-CSVs-into-SQL-216223d9

And finally you can use your own invoke-expression command without any powershell variables or even keep a proc in your DB that you can execute via powershell.

Comment: Can you give an example please ?

Answer (score 0):

Your method is wrong.

1. Import your datas into your database, in tabletemporary1 by example
2. Do only one update with tabletemporary1 join on your table DocStatus

For 1. you can loop on your files and write in a datatable (datatable with same structure of tabletemporary1) and also use bulkcopy  ([example here](http://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-sql-server/bulk-copy-data-sql-server-powershell)).
If you are not on SQL Server you can use import file tool or sqlcommand by default.